# Way to check where the function is defined on C++

Tags: c++, function, analysis, lint

When working on a big project, I would like to know in which header file a particular function is defined. Is there a way to do that for  C++ in Ubunt (linux)?

Comment: Most development environments keep track of that for you. This is not a C++ question per se but a build environment question and will depend on the tools you are using.

Comment: I use `grep` or `ripgrep`.

Comment: grep is useful when there is no overload

Comment: @MartinYork ah yes, you are right. I'll modify the question

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the GNU Debugger (GDB). Given a function name, `MYFUNCTION`, a binary file `MYFILE.o`, and some optional arguments, `MYARGS` (delimited by spaces), you can run the following:

```
gdb -batch -ex "break MYFUNCTION" -ex "run" --ex "info line" --args MYFILE.o MYARGS | grep -P "Line [0-9]+"
```

If the function was called, the output will look like:

> Line 1234 of "../path/to/function.c" starts at address 0x7ffff7d9e1a3
> <MYFUNCTION+16> and ends at 0x7ffff7d9e1aa <MYFUNCTION+23>.

Otherwise, the output will return:

> Function "MYFUNCTION" not defined.

- Note: Be sure to enable debugging when compiling the file (in GCC and G++, it's the `-g` flag).
- Documentation: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.pdf

Answer (score 0):

One method which helps me is through editor called `Vs code`. Just pointing the cursor on the function name and pressing `F12` or in some machines `Fn+F12` will let you to the function definition's location. Other editors should have this as well...

To note: This is a specific way and not a general solution to your problem.

Comment: I use vim for editing. May be I should invest in IDE

Comment: I was hoping something like gdb can solve this problem